# How to have a popup scrolling in the same way that others elements?

Tags: gwt, popup, scroll

I can not solve my problem. As example, my website : www.mananaseguro.com.
In the home page, I have some popup appearing just under movies's poster (when the mouse is over the poster). But when I scroll UP (for example), the popup will not appear just under the poster. Their is a space between them. I tried to add the popup to the home's page panel but it did not succeed.

So is it possible to simulate the good popup behavior? (the popup must stay under the poster).
Or more precisely, is it possible to attach a DecoratedPopupPanel to another panel inside the page in order to have the popup scrolling in the same way that others elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive good popup behavior by using below property.

```
popup.setPopupPosition(left, top)
```

Pass movie image x and y index position in top and left. and make consistent look and fill.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [PopupPanel#showRelativeTo()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#showRelativeTo%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject%29) method.

Comment: I tried the solution, something was misunderstood in my question...Indeed, with showRelativeTo(), the popup will appear "under" the element BUT it does not change anything when I scroll because the popup does not stay under the image when scrolling. The popup is related to the Root node, that is why the popup always stay at the same absolute position after scrolling. I tried to add a MouseWheelEvent() to calculate the new position after scrolling, but it was without success because IT SEEMS I can not get the new coordinates of the image after scrolling. Any idea ?